# Simplifying $\binom{n}{0} - \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} - \binom{n}{3} + \cdots + (-1)^n \binom{n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

> Simplify the expression 
>   $$\binom{n}{0} - \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} - \binom{n}{3} + \cdots + (-1)^n \binom{n}{n}$$ 
>   for positive $n$.

I tried to find a one-to-one correspondence but I'm stuck.

Can anyone help?